# I want to change the string of letters xxx-xxx-xxxx into 333-333-3333 I tried this but getting an error in the if(phoneNumber.charAt(0))

Tags: java

```
public class ABCTelephoneTranslator {

public static String translate(String phoneNumber) {
     // Creating array of string length 
    char[] ch = new char[phoneNumber.length()]; 

    // Copy character by character into array 
    for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length(); i++) { 
        ch[i] = phoneNumber.charAt(i); 
    } 
   
    // Printing content of array 
    for (char c : ch) { 
        System.out.println(c); 
    }
    System.out.println(ch.length);
    if(ch.length > 12) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("the format should be XXX-XXX-XXXX");
    }
    if(phoneNumber.charAt(0) == "x") {
        phoneNumber.charAt(0) = "3";
    }
    return phoneNumber;
}
```

I need to change the string of letters xxx-xxx-xxxx into 333-333-3333 how do i do that I tried this but getting an error where it says if(phoneNumber.charat(0) == "x") and below that please help me resolve this thank you

Comment: `charAt()` returns a `char`, not a `String`. So you have to compare the value to a `char`, not a `String` (the expression `"x"` is a `String`, but `'x'` is a `char`).

Comment: Probably set the refresh on his script for 5 seconds rather than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

There are easier ways to do this but to answer your specific question you need to do the following.  At the end of your method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
   if(ch[i] == 'x' { // single quotes.
        ch[i] = '3';
   }
}
return new String(ch);
```

Also, to get the array of characters you can do.

```
char ch[] = phonenumber.toCharArray();
```

And contrary to what others have told you,

```
phonenumber.replace("x","3");
```

Doesn't work because `String`s are immutable.  You need to reassign it.

```
phonenumber = phonenumber.replace("x","3");
```

Answer (score 1):

`charAt` functionr returns a character. You cannot use it to compare it to a string. You need to compare it to a character. So, your if-condition should be `phoneNumber.charAt(0) == 'x'`

It would help you to go through the [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))

Answer (score 0):

Try using "`phoneNumber.replace("x","3");`" It should replace the 'X's with '3's